# Preventing newbies from asking the whole freaking problem statement

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter, bad-questions

I have come across questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63201513/write-in-c-language) frequently, and have always noted that such questions are usually asked by newbies, who do not know how to ask on SO. However, I think such questions can be prevented if we put in place a mechanism to allow a non-code question to be allowed by an account only if the account has `>10` reputation. Why don't we put in place such a constraint?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe that would help. Maybe instead there would be a rash of questions that end in `please help` (formatted as code).

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 - yeah, I know, I have nothing against your question :) Just noting that this case is not even a problem statement, it is a blatant copy-paste

Comment: @AndrewMyers, I know, but people will always try to work around the restrictions (example: adding spam text to get around too much code error). Isn't that why we have moderation? To catch what stupid computers can't? ;)

Comment: What's so magical about including some code? In my experience, the presence of code doesn't make these low-quality questions any better. It's also going in the wrong direction. Not all questions on Stack Overflow require code. This isn't a "debug-my-code-for-me" site.

Comment: @CodyGray, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63201643/how-to-make-an-array-of-classes-in-c). The question will probably be flagged as a duplicate, but it still is "acceptable" (don't get me wrong here)

Comment: Yes, that's a debugging question. That's only one of many types of questions that are on-topic for Stack Overflow. In particular, it's the most boring and least generally useful type, so I'd rather *discourage* those, rather than encourage them.

Comment: More on topic: sometimes no-code questions are fine (I can attest for certain issues with Google Cloud Projects for example), and I agree with Cody here - code or no code the question likely won't become better (and also might lead to meta posts by legit users frustrated with not being able to post a question without a snippet).

Comment: @CodyGray, you got me wrong ;) It definitely shows what the OP wants to do and helps us help him, as he's taken the efforts to at least try the problem :)

Comment: RE: "and also might lead to meta posts by legit users frustrated with not being able to post a question without a snippet" @OlegValter, that's why low reputation (>10) required :)

Comment: Separated from the previous comment: that said, a warning of sorts can be triggered by certain keywords like "not working", "has an error", etc that prompts to provide code if none is present

Comment: This could use some stats. If it can be shown that 99% of no-code questions from <10 rep users will be downvoted and closed, then maybe a simple block could be useful.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 - I don't know, I really don't - something tells me such a low barrier won't do. If you want to go through with it - go all in, say, 1K or 2K rep, or even higher. 10 rep is a single upvote on a single question currently... Also, how do you define "no code"? Is it lack of backticks in the body, should they be matched? Does a single `this` count as code?

Comment: @OlegValter, how have we implemented too much code error?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 - actually, I don't know, I never had a first-hand encounter with it, but it seems like it works on code blocks

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 - btw, here you are, small SEDE query showing how many questions by users with 10 rep or less that are downvoted or closed and are without code (~28% this year of total posted and downvoted or closed, so not that much): https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1270081/questions-without-code-in-body-since-period-that-are-downvoted-or-closed?offset=1&period=year. Please, note that the query does not account for questions without proper code formatting and may have missed something - feedback welcome.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 don't mention - my hobby of sorts :) On a serious note: the data shows that no-code questions from very low-rep users fare surprisingly ok, even I expected a higher number, so it is likely that the issue is not as bad as it seems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "newbies" and is also not related to how to ask a question on SO but rather how to generally ask a good and precise question that can be answered by someone else. SO is not special in about judging if it is a useful or not useful question.

To improve this you need to change people's attidute and/or their education (non-coding related), their empathy for getting into the potential answer's mind or simply their time constraint and in some cases probably also their layziness.

No tool, restriction, whatsoever will prevent those kind of questions to happen.

Answer (score 5):

Posting the entire problem description is annoying, but at least it's better than a vaguely specified problem, where you have to extract the necessary details bit by bit via comments, and meanwhile answers come rolling in by people who are trying to guess those details...

The real issue with that question *isn't* with what the OP posted, it's with what they *didn't* post: they didn't ask an actual question, and they didn't give us even a hint of their thoughts on how to write code for that homework assignment / coding challenge.

IMHO, we don't need some automated system to block such questions. The standard tools of down & close voting are sufficient. True, sometimes rep farmers will manage to post an answer before the question is closed, but that's only a problem if those answers are upvoted, since that makes it harder for the question to be deleted.

Of course, it's *possible* that the OP will respond to comments and convert their "homework dump" into a useful question. But that doesn't happen very often, IME.